# como redireccionar enlaces erroneos a index.php con php mvc

Tags: php, mvc

Hola estoy creando una pagina landing page con php mvc, estoy intentando hacer que al introducir un texto "x" por ejemplo: asdas esta rediriga al inicio, asi para evitar ataques y todo el asunto, segui un curso de udemy pero solo puedo redirigir con un login, y en esta pagina solo muestro información.

codigo

controller.php

```
class MvcController{

#LLAMADA A LA PLANTILLA
#-------------------------------------

public function pagina(){   

    include "views/template.php";

}

#ENLACES
#-------------------------------------

public function enlacesPaginasController(){

    if(isset( $_GET['action'])){

        $enlaces = $_GET['action'];

    }

    else{

        $enlaces = "index";
    }

    $respuesta = Paginas::enlacesPaginasModel($enlaces);

    include $respuesta;

}

}
```

controlador enlaces.php

```
<?php

class Enlaces{

    public function enlacesController(){

                if(isset($_GET["action"])){

            $enlaces = $_GET["action"];

        }

        else{

            $enlaces = "index";

        }

        $respuesta = EnlacesModels::enlacesModel($enlaces);

        include $respuesta;

    }


}
```

modelo enlaces.php

```
<?php 

class Paginas{

    public function enlacesPaginasModel($enlaces){

    if($enlaces == "index" ){

            $module =  "views/modules/".$enlaces.".php";

        }

        else{

            $module =  "views/modules/index.php";

        }

        return $module;

    }

    }
```

index.php

```
<?php

 require_once "models/enlaces.php";
 require_once "controllers/enlaces.php";
 require_once "controllers/controller.php";

 $mvc = new MvcController();
 $mvc -> pagina();
```

y por ultimo el .htacess

```
  # Impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio

  Options All -Indexes

  # Url Amigables

  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ /index.php?action=$1
```

he intentado durante horas para buscar una solución de hecho busque acá en stackoverflow si algo podía ayudarme pero no lo logro hacer funcionar, cree una lista blanca de palabras pero la unica lista blanca de palabras sería index

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido que acceda a nuevas páginas.

Estructura de directorios y archivos:

En mi caso en el ***localhost/carpetas/283782*** esa donde tengo alojado los archivos.

```
 controllers
      |___ controller.php
 models
      |___ enlaces.php
 views
      |___ modules
              |____ hola.php
              |____ index.php
 .htaccess
 index.php
 404.php
```

---

## Archivos

**.htaccess**

```
# Impedir que se pueda ver el listado de contenidos de un directorio

  Options All -Indexes

  # Url Amigables

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /carpetas/283782
  RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ index.php?action=$1
```

---

**index.php**

```
<?php
 require_once "models/enlaces.php";
 require_once "controllers/controller.php";

 $mvc = new MvcController();

 $mvc->enlacesPaginasController();
```

---

**controllers/controller.php**

```
<?php

require_once "./models/enlaces.php";

class MvcController{

  #LLAMADA A LA PLANTILLA
  #-------------------------------------


  private $paginas;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->paginas = new Paginas();
  }


  #ENLACES
  #-------------------------------------

  public function enlacesPaginasController(){

      if(isset( $_GET['action'])){
          $enlaces = $_GET['action'];
      } else {
          $enlaces = "index";
      }

      $respuesta = $this->paginas->enlacesPaginasModel($enlaces);
      include $respuesta;
  }

}

?>
```

---

**models/enlaces.php**

```
<?php

class Paginas{

  public function enlacesPaginasModel($enlaces){


      $module =  "./views/modules/".$enlaces.".php";

      if (file_exists($module)) {
      } else {
        $module = "./404.php";
      }

      return $module;

    }

}
```

---

**views/modules/hola.php**

```
<h1>Hola</h1>
```

---

**views/modules/index.php**

```
<h1>INDEX</h1>
```

---

**404.php**

```
<h1>404</h1>
```

---

He realizado cambios muy mínimos.

**Cambios en .htaccess**

En el `.htaccess` puse un `RewriteBase` y elimine la barra `/` de dealten de `index.php`

**Cambios en index.php**

Cambie el método `pagina()` por `enlacesPaginasController()`.

**Cambios en controllers/controller.php**

- `require_once` para modles/enlcaes.php
- Eliminar método `pagina()`
- Llamar a `enlacesPagiasModel()` como método público no static.

**Cambios en models/enlaces.php**

- Simplificar clase.
- Path correcto para la url.

---

> Este código puede funcionar para comprender el modelo MVC. Es muy
>   mejorable. Pero suficiente para ver un esqueleto **MVC** en **PHP**